# Can't map props passed to my React Router's Link component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am passing props from my parent like this:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.recipes).map(key => {
  return (
    <Link
      key={key}
      to={{
        pathname: `/view/${key}`,
        state: {
          recipe: this.state.recipes[key]
        }
      }}
    >
      <Recipe
        key={key}
        index={key}
        recipe={this.state.recipes[key]}
        deleteRecipe={this.deleteRecipe}
        editRecipe={this.editRecipe}
      />
    </Link>
  );
})}
```

This is how my router looks:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/view/:recipeId" component={ViewRecipe} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And from this component, I am trying to access that props

**ViewRecipe.js**

```
class ViewRecipe extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { recipe: {} }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { recipe } = this.props.location.state;
    this.setState({ recipe: recipe });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <h1>{this.state.recipe.recipeName}</h1>
    <img src={this.state.recipe.dishImg} alt="Dish" />
        <ul>
           {this.state.recipe.ingredients.map( ingredient => <li>{ingredient}</li>)}
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>direction</li>
          <li>direction</li>
          <li>direction</li>
          <li>direction</li>
          <li>directio</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My **ViewRecipe.js** state looks like this: [image]

The recipeName and the dishImg render correctly but when I try to map my ingredients I get the following error [image]

Comment: What is the value of recipe in `componentDidMount` ?

Comment: This error is most likely occurring because the ingredients array is null or undefined at the time of `render`

Comment: "location": {
    "pathname": "/view/recipe1",
    "search": "",
    "hash": "",
    "state": {
      "recipe": {
        "recipeName": "Ham And Cheese Breakfast Pockets",
        "ingredients": [
          "Prod 1",
          "Prod 2",
          "Prod 3"
        ],
        "directions": [
          "Frist Direction",
          "Second Direction",
          "Third Direction"
        ],
        "dishImg": "https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=1"
      }
    },
    "key": "ripdex"
  },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be undefined

```
    <ul>
       {this.state.recipe.ingredients.map( ingredient => <li>{ingredient}</li>)}
    </ul>
```

For this you have to modified code like this to work

```
    <ul>
       {this.state.recipe && this.state.recipe.ingredients && this.state.recipe.ingredients.map( ingredient => <li>{ingredient}</li>)}
    </ul>
```

Above we are checking is all are defined before doing map hope this will work

Edit:

You cannot use .map function for non arrays. null.map results to undefined :)

Comment: How about `this.state.recipe && this.state.recipe.ingredients.length ? this.state.recipe.ingredients.map(...) : null`? So that, we prevent the `map` from executing unless we have some data in `ingredients` array.

Comment: Yaa we can do the change this.state.recipe && this.state.recipe.ingredients.length && this.state.recipe.ingredients.map(...) like that but i don't think ternary operator needed here because it will not go until array has some value (this.state.recipe.ingredients.length )